# open remote (ssh) file locally via comand line (without installing sshfs)

Tags: command-line, ssh, nautilus, remote, sftp

currently I use Nautilus to connect to server, and then double click on the files I want to open. I am trying to figure out a way to do this purely from terminal. The internet revealed `sshfs`, but that is not currently installed, and since Nautilus can do it already, I should be able to replicate that behavoir without installing anything new, right?

I guess what I am really trying to do is replicate the behavoir of nautilus's connecting to a sever in the command line. Right now these are the options I have found and the reasons they aren't quite what I am looking for

1. `ssh -X USER@SERVER.ETC` After connecting, I can open files, but they aren't opened remotely. This is great, but there is a performance penalty (gui lags) as compared to opening the files locally, and critically for me audio is not present.
2. `sftp` is great, but I can't open files from the `sftp` command prompt. `gvfs-open` yields `Invalid command.` If instead I do

   `!gvfs-open sftp://SERVER/PATH_TO_FILE`

   I get the following error

   `gvfs-open: sftp://SERVER/PAth_TO_FILE: error opening location: The specified location is not mounted
   Shell exited with status 2`

If I connect to the server via Nautilus first (and this is an `sftp` conection) I *can* execute
 `gvfs-open sftp://SERVER/PATH_TO_FILE`
and open the file locally. How do I do this purely from the terminal? And what is Nautilus doing differently than executing `sftp` from the terminal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in your command line workflow is:

- Start with `gvfs-mount ssh://your-server/`
- then access files normally with local applications - for example, `gedit /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=your-server/path/to/file.txt`